# Which JS technique: select parent of targeted element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure that the terms in the question are correct; however I have some HTML (and unfortunately, I am stuck with its structure):

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#turn-left">Turn left</a></li>
    <li><a href="#turn-right">Turn right</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="possible-outcome">
  <span id="turn-left"></span>
  <p>You step into a puddle.</p>
</div>

<div class="possible-outcome">
  <span id="turn-right"></span>
  <p>You fall into a ditch.</p>
</div>
```

What I would like is all `possible-outcome` `div`s to become hidden by having:

```
div.non-actual-outcome {display: none;}
```

applied to them, as soon as the user selects one of the hyperlinks, except for the  `div` containing the `span` with the target `id`, which should have the `actual-outcome` class applied to it by JS, so it and it alone is displayed:

```
div.actual-outcome {display: block;}
```

When the user hits some other link to a `span` in a `possible-outcome` `div`, then *that* `div` will become the only one visible (until the user hits a link that isn't to one of those spans).

Here is some sample code:

```css
div.non-actual-outcome {
  display: none;
}

div.actual-outcome {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#turn-left">Turn left</a></li>
    <li><a href="#turn-right">Turn right</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="possible-outcome">
  <span id="turn-left"></span>
  <p>You step into a puddle.</p>
</div>

<div class="possible-outcome">
  <span id="turn-right"></span>
  <p>You fall into a ditch.</p>
</div>
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this (and the correct terms in which to ask the question)?

Comment: Why would you put the IDs on the child spans instead of on the divs themselves?

Comment: _and unfortunately, I am stuck with its structure_: are you also stuck with the classes, or can you modify those?

Comment: Could you maybe hide the contents of the `<div>`s instead of the `<div>`s themselves? That wouldn’t need any JavaScript: `.possible-outcome > * { display: none; } :target ~ * { display: block; }`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Unfortunately the IDs on the child spans are part of the structure I am stuck with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a common class to all your `a` elements so that they can be distinguished, for example `class="tab"`:

```
<a class="tab" href="#turn-left">Turn left</a>
```

Second, hide all `div` elements by default by adding the `display:none` property to the CSS selector `.possible-outcome` (which all `div` elements have):

```
div.possible-outcome {
  display: none;
}
```

and use only `actual-outcome` to hide/show the `div` you want. No need to use two classes for that, just one will do. If the `div` has the class `actual-outcome` then it will be shown, if not then it won't (because it has the class `possible-outcome`).

Third, when a `.tab` element get clicked, select its target `span` along with that `span`'s parent and do some logic: if the `span` exists and its parent is not currently shown (not having the class `actual-outcome`), then hide the actually shown `div` (if exists) and show the current `span`'s parent instead.

**Note:** If you want to show a `div` by default just add the class `actual-outcome` to it:

```
<div class="possible-outcome actual-outcome">
```

**Full code:**

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  var target = ev.target;                                               // get the element that has been clicked
  if(target.classList.contains("tab")) {                                // if the clicked element is a .tab element
    var span = document.querySelector(target.getAttribute("href")),     // then select that .tab's span to show
        parent = span.parentElement;                                    // select the parent of that span (perhaps check if the span exists first to not get the "can't access property parentElement of null")
    if(span && !parent.classList.contains("actual-outcome")) {          // if the span exists and its parent is not currently shown (not having the class "actual-outcome")
      var visibleOutcome = document.querySelector(".actual-outcome");   // then select the current shown element (which we know will have the class "actuall-outcome")
      if(visibleOutcome) {                                              // if there is one
        visibleOutcome.classList.remove("actual-outcome");              // hide it by remove the class "actual-outcome" from its classList
      }
      parent.classList.add("actual-outcome");                           // and show the current span's parent by adding that same old class
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div.possible-outcome {
  display: none;
}

div.actual-outcome {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="tab" href="#turn-left">Turn left</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab" href="#turn-right">Turn right</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="possible-outcome">
  <span id="turn-left"></span>
  <p>You step into a puddle.</p>
</div>

<div class="possible-outcome">
  <span id="turn-right"></span>
  <p>You fall into a ditch.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to adapt this to get a working demo of what I was trying to achieve. The code comments were especially useful.

Comment: I've added our implementation of this as an answer, for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completion, the [Divio Cloud interactive debugging checklist for deployments](http://docs.divio.com/en/latest/how-to/debug-deployment-problems.html) is our implementation of the solution to this problem.

It's like a [choose your own adventure story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choose_Your_Own_Adventure) in our Sphinx documentation, to help users identify why a deployment may have failed.

It was was developed on the basis of [Ibrahim Mahrir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49636212/2422705):

One of our actual JS experts (i.e. not me) used my working proof-of-concept based on Ibrahim's answer for the final version.

The JavaScript and CSS are both embedded in the page itself.

The HTML structure is largely determined by the output from Sphinx, hence the need to accommodate the arrangement of elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I could come up with. This does not modify the structure by adding any other classes than the ones provided.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#turn-left">Turn left</a></li>
    <li><a href="#turn-right">Turn right</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="possible-outcome">
  <span id="turn-left"></span>
  <p>You step into a puddle.</p>
</div>

<div class="possible-outcome">
  <span id="turn-right"></span>
  <p>You fall into a ditch.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.non-actual-outcome {
  display: none;
}

div.actual-outcome {
  display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
var outcomeDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('possible-outcome') // selects all divs and returns them as an array
var links = document.querySelectorAll('li') // selects all <li> and returns them as array


// This is turn left li, we will hide turn-right when clicking it.
links[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
  outcomeDivs[1].classList.add('non-actual-outcome'); // hides turn-right
  links[1].style.display = 'none'; // hides other link
});
// This is turn right li, we will hide turn-left when clicking it.
links[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
  outcomeDivs[0].classList.add('non-actual-outcome'); // hides turn-left
  links[0].style.display = 'none'; // hides other link
});
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BrPpbE?editors=1111)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this relies on a static list of links, whereas there will be many - including more in each `possible-outcome` `div` - so it won't work for my case.

Comment: Well, if there are more possible-outcome divs then the list will just increase in size and you'd just have to access the new divs by their index. So, don't stop at [1], but continue on. The same can be applied to the links.